# sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command

Tags: shell, sed

I have the following shellscript

```
for i in {1..15..1}
do
  sed -i 's/r2.chk/r'$i'.chk' ./ex${i}/r2.gjf
done
```

which associates to `r2.gjf` in `/ex1`, `/ex2`, etc, it has a line includes `r2.chk`.

When I run `./sed.sh`, I got
`` sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command ``

I found many similar questions on stackoverflow. But, still unsure what's my problem here :(

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script to enable logging.

Comment: BTW, note that `{1..15..1}` is not a standard POSIX feature. If by "shell" you mean you're using "sh", that'd be your problem right there.

Comment: For _bash_, I'd strongly recommend `for ((i=1; i<=15; i++))` (which runs in constant memory, unlike the brace expansion form). For _sh_, `i=0; while [ "$i" -lt 15 ]; do ...; i=$((i + 1)); done`

Comment: Thanks. I got ```++ for i in '{1..15..1}'
++ sed -i s/r2.chk/r1.chk ./ex1/r2.gjf
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command
``` after ```set -x``` in my script. I will check your for comment.

Comment: It works before :(, no ```#!/bin/sh```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run ./sed.sh, I got sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command

So terminate the s command - it's missing the `/`.

```
sed 's/r2.chk/r'$i'.chk/'
                       ^ - here
```